# Silverlight DataGridRow Background color change based on a column value and bind from the datagrid itemsource

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I am trying to color the row based on a column value and may be other calculations in the value converter, but as long as I set the background value to any binding or anything but the hardcoded color Value="Red" in the setter, it throws a XAML parsing error. I am implementing like this:

```
<sdk:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding
EmailJobs}"
AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
Height="Auto"
HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
Name="dgEmailJObs"
VerticalAlignment="Top" 
Width="Auto"       Grid.Row="2">


<sdk:DataGrid.RowStyle>
                <Style TargetType="sdk:DataGridRow">
                    <Style.Setters>
                          <Setter Property="Background"
Value="{Binding Path=Status,
Converter={StaticResource
valueConverter}}"/>
                    </Style.Setters>
                </Style>
            </sdk:DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
                <sdk:DataGridTextColumn
CanUserReorder="False"
CanUserResize="False"
CanUserSort="True" Header="Customer"
Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding
Customer}" />
                <sdk:DataGridTextColumn
CanUserReorder="False"
CanUserResize="False"
CanUserSort="True" Header="Program"
Width="Auto"  Binding="{Binding
Program}" />
                <sdk:DataGridTextColumn
CanUserReorder="False"
CanUserResize="False"
CanUserSort="True"
Header="Application" Width="Auto" 
Binding="{Binding Application}"/>
                <sdk:DataGridTextColumn
CanUserReorder="True" 
CanUserResize="False"
CanUserSort="True" Header="Status"
Width="Auto"  Binding="{Binding
Status}"></sdk:DataGridTextColumn>
                <sdk:DataGridTextColumn
CanUserReorder="False"
CanUserResize="False"
CanUserSort="True" Header="Last
Created By" Width="Auto" 
Binding="{Binding LastChangedBy}"/>
                <sdk:DataGridTextColumn
CanUserReorder="False"
CanUserResize="False"
CanUserSort="True" Header="Last
Created On" Width="Auto" 
                           Binding="{Binding
LastChangedOn,StringFormat='MM/DD/YYYY
hh:mm tt'}" />
            </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>                       
        </sdk:DataGrid>
```

I am using MVVM and dont wanna use the triggering event. All I want is to simply supply the fourth column value to the converter, but it blows up, should be pretty simple jsut lack of XAML binding knowledge :( any help

Comment: Hoi Kazi, could you post the error message, and the code of your converter ?

Comment: the error is just a generic xaml parsing error, no details available. the error happens the line I declare Value="{Binding Path=Status, Converter={StaticResource valueConverter}}", the value converter is pretty simple like this

Answer (score 2):

I think I see... Silverlight 4 doesn't allow (anymore) bindings into Setters.

However there are 2 simple solutions to solve your issue :

- You can remove the `<sdk:DataGrid.RowStyle>` and its content and replace it by `RowStyle="{Binding Path=Status, Converter={StaticResource valueConverter}}"` as a property of your datagrid (example below)

  `<sdk:DataGrid Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding EmailJobs}" RowStyle="{Binding Path=Status, Converter={StaticResource valueConverter}}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Name="dgEmailJObs" Width="Auto" Margin="0,0,0,87" LoadingRow="dgEmailJObs_LoadingRow">`

Or, you can manage it in the code behind after triggering the event LoadingRow:

```
void dgEmailJObs_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
{
    myClass c = e.Row.DataContext as myClass;
    if (c != null)
    {
        if (c.Status == "Stopped")
        {
            e.Row.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        }
        else
        {
            e.Row.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope that helps ;)

Comment: thanks Slyvain, but that wouldnt even call the value converter class at all now and also dont give any error.

Comment: actually now its not finding the property as I got in the output: BindingExpression path error: 'Status' property not found on 'x.y.MM.EmailStartStop.ViewModel.EmailJobControlViewModel', Status is a property of a coustom object that goes inside the collections of the property EmailJobs whihc binds to the itemsource of the datagrid from view model, how can I mentions the path here ?

Comment: Indeed, after tests, the solution with RowStyle doesn't work. However the solution with the LoadingRow event works fine. I made a little app if you want to see what might be the differences with your code : http://www.megaupload.com/?d=VBD53B6K

Answer (score 1):

```
private void grdPendingRequest_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
{
    string changedColPath = string.Empty;
    dynamic itemData = (dynamic)e.Row.DataContext;
    if (itemData != null)
        changedColPath = itemData.Changed_Field;

    if (changedColPath != string.Empty)
    {
        string colPath;
        System.Windows.Data.Binding binding;
        string[] ChangedColNameList = null;

        foreach (DataGridColumn col in grdPendingRequest.Columns)
        {
            if (col is DataGridBoundColumn)
            {
                binding = (col as DataGridBoundColumn).Binding;
                colPath = binding.Path.Path;
                ChangedColNameList = changedColPath.Split(';');

                if (ChangedColNameList.Contains(colPath))
                {
                    FrameworkElement felt = col.GetCellContent(e.Row);
                    FrameworkElement felt_result = GetParent(felt, typeof(DataGridCell));
                    if (felt_result != null)
                    {
                        DataGridCell cell = (DataGridCell)felt_result;
                        //cell.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 196, 219, 249));
                        cell.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Some explanation would be nice

Answer (score 0):

my value converter:

```
public class EmailJobStatusConverter:IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (value.ToString()=="Stopped") ? 
                new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red) : 
                new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        SolidColorBrush resultColor = value as SolidColorBrush;

        if (resultColor.Color == Colors.Green)
        {
            return "Green";
        }
        else 
            return "Red";
    }
}
```